# google cloud build: simple test file not found even though shows up with ls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Trying to run a simple bash script on google cloud build. Trying to run it it says it cannot find it, even though `ls` shows it is there

I've set up a build trigger on google cloud to run a simple test repository on pushes to main branch

The test repository has just two files: the cloudbuild yaml and a simple `testfile.sh` bash script

Cloudbuild yaml tells it to run this `testfile.sh` file, but says it cannot find it even though a simple `ls` arg shows it

I've tried like every combination of ways to run a bash file:

- with/without '-c' argument
- with/without '.' argument
- with/without file shebang

`cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'ubuntu'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'testfile.sh']
```

`testfile.sh`:

```sh
echo "Go suck it, world!"
```

`gcloud builds log <log-id>`:

```
starting build "640c5ba5-5906-4296-a80c-9adc54ee84bb"

FETCHSOURCE
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/test-wtf-2734586432/r/test-files
 * branch            1d6fc0b27c09cb3421a242764dfe28bc115bf8f5 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 1d6fc0b Fix typo in entrypoint
BUILD
Pulling image: ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:adf73ca014822ad8237623d388cedf4d5346aa72c270c5acc01431cc93e18e2d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest
bash: testfile.sh: command not found
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "ubuntu" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it

Had to get rid of the `'-c'` from the `args` list